# Rise time and clock frequency: when does it start biting me?

Tags: pcb, transmission-line, clock-speed

I have spent quite a bit of time reading (mostly the questions and answers on here) about rise times of square waves and how they can cause transmission line effects (reflection, ringing, etc.).

Everyone seems to be talking about rules of thumbs about when to worry and throwing numbers around without actually explaining where they come from. So here are a few questions that still remain in my head after all the reading:

1. Assuming a speed of 150mm/ns (on FR-4 PCB), if I have a square wave with a rise time of 1ns, at what trace length do I have to start using terminating resistors? Do I use series or parallel termination? What about bidirectional lines?
2. Do I have to worry about rise time and trace length when my clock frequency is say 10kHz? 1MHz? People say rise time is what matters, not the frequency. So regardless of my signal frequency, I have to worry about rise time?

It's really foggy for me because people seem to talk about 1/3, 1/4, 1/5 wavelength trace lengths as limit for terminating resistors, some people say 1/10 of the electric length... So I appreciate if someone can clear it for me.

Comment: At 10 kHz you worry, at 1 mHz not. Think about how long an emissions test takes and whether offending transitions happen in this duration. At 1 mHz it would be *tolerable* from an EMC perspective, if the function of your device is fine with a the ringing transition

Comment: I apologize - I meant 1MHz and not 1mHz... Edited the question.

Comment: @Ozbekov did you just discover the milli-hertz ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO there is no hard limit. I always series terminate my lines **if** the driver impedance is much lower than the trace impedance and I can't literally put sender and receiver next to each other. You can't really be sure about the rise time of your components, so it could be much shorter than advertised under some conditions.

All it takes is a single cheap resistor, which is probably in the BOM anyway, so why risk unterminated lines?

Now about that IF: Many IC, like ADCs actually have outputs with a rather high impedance of 50-100 Ohm, so there is no need to terminate them. Same goes for HC logic (not for LVC!).

About the frequency: I would start to worry if transitions are more regular than about 1 Hz. You could push your luck and skip termination for certain status lines that toggle rarely..But again: why? Once they flip, they ring, this can harm other functions, and not only your EMC report.

I have never needed parallel termination for data so far, but I have not done Gbit interfaces. Parallel termination is "cleaner" but power hungry, so should be used only if series isn't good enough.

Comment: Do you account for the output impedance of the pin you're driving that line through? So I suspect the series terminator resistance should be: trace Z_o **minus** pin output Z. Is that correct? Even then, though, if you have a high Z input at the end, it will cause ringing and reflections, is that right?

Comment: @Ozbekov yes line impedance minus output impedance for best match. High speed things like clock buffer give the pin output impedance in the datasheet for this reason. Series termination will *always* lead to one single reflection at the receiver. But there are no further reflections (ringing) because, the pulse is absorbed at the sender upon return.

Comment: Thank you, this clears quite a bit for me. I'll just terminate my lines to be on the safe side. Would I also have to worry about analog lines (non-RF)? Say, for example, the output of an op amp or the emitter of a photoresistor? What non-digital signals do I have to worry about terminating?

Comment: @Ozbekov if your signals have low frequency content, it wouldn't be necessary due to edge rinning. However, EMI might still couple onto your long analog traces from other places, so it is a good practise to still put RC filters on your analog lines with a cutoff at least about 10x higher than your planned signals. If the accuracy penalty is not tolerable I would omit this though and aim for very tight layout in this area.

Comment: Thank you very much